# The Add node isn't working for me, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: procedural

I have two textures I generated with gradient, greater than, etc. and I used an add node to add them together, but only one part is showing and I don't know why. I'm making a baseball procedurally. [image: error] This is the result.[image: top][image: bottom] Here are the textures I am trying to add.

nodes:
[image: nodes]

Comment: Show us your Node tree or provide blend file

Comment: And instead of „add node isn’t working“ you should ask: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Chris I added the node tree.

Comment: You added just parts - lines is a custom node. Add your blend file

Comment: Where do I upload the blend file to?

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/L6rv2ak1

Comment: Your values are going out of normalized range. Clamp your subtract nodes.

Comment: that worked, do I answer or do you?

Comment: You can answer if you want. Make sure to mark it as accepted. Just so you know what's going on - 0 is supposed to be pure black and 1 is supposed to be pure white, but blender can work with values outside these ranges. When you subtracted, some operation left the black areas substantially less than 0, so even when "white" was added, it still didn't bring it above the 0 mark and those areas stayed (unintuitively) black.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't clamp my subtract nodes, which were below 1, so clamping the nodes placed them back to normal again.